# cant load file inside directory

Tags: php, html

Having a weird problem.

Simple php website,

root

```
page.php
another-page.php
css/
images/
services/
   service-name.php
   another-service-name.php
```

This is basically what my structure looks like slimmed down.

So when i go to localhost/page.php it shows the page, but if i try to access any file inside the services folder i get a 500 http error.

The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

Im using Mamp setup to host the website locally.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the error log, inside of you Apache server log folder

Comment: set the folder permission as `777` or php file permission as 644

Comment: Sorry stupid stupid mistake aha

Comment: Basically forgot to add ../ to my <?php require('header'); ?>

Comment: 500 error shows means issue in php code refer link to find error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display/37036144#37036144